# Native PHP Session values are lost in Codeigniter

Tags: php, session, session-variables, codeigniter-3

I am working on a project that uses native **PHP** `sessions`. I redirect user to **Codeigniter** page and all the session values are lost.
I tried using Nativesession library, it helps me retain all the native *php session* data and same is true if I use `session_start()` in `index.php` of Codeigniter but I get notice messages saying "*A session is active, You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time*" and "*A session had already been started - ignoring* `session_start()`"

Comment: Have you tried $_SESSION ?

Comment: yes. tried var_dump($_SESSION), It stores only the values which were updated in Codeigniter environment and all the previous values are not shown(lost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading about how the session library works in codeigniter, figured out the root cause of the problem.

As per documentation,

"*When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid session cookie is sent by the user’s browser. If a sessions cookie does not exist (or if it doesn’t match one stored on the server or has expired) a new session will be created and saved.*"

In my case, when I use *PHP Native sessions*, it doesn't create valid cookies for CI and as per above statement, **CI will create new session** hence old session will be destroyed.

there are two ways to get around this

1. suppress the Warnings and notices generated by *CI session library* by using `@$this->load->library('session')`
2. Don't load the *CI session library* at all and keep using Native PHP sessions.

Hope it helps if anyone is facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to start the session like this

add this to your controller constructor

```
$this->load->library('session')
```

you can use the session like this

```
$this->session
```

add data

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_key', 'some_value');
```

fetch data

```
$some_value = $this->session->userdata('some_key');
```

Read the docs

[**Codeigniter Session Management**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help. I have already tried it, I had to use session_start() because the above stated method was not working for me( somehow my native php session values are lost).

Comment: can you share Session and cookie definitions in you config.php ?

Comment: @BRjava $config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['cookie_path']  = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;